# Return statement in perl

Tags: perl, return-value

ss1.[image: ss2]I am new to Perl and I have a simple question. I have a if else statement.

```
if ( $response->is_success ) {
    do something;
} else {
    my @vals = foo();

    sub foo {
        return
            "Total closed cases:0",
            "Total pending cases:0",
            "Total resolved cases:0",
            "Total assigned cases:0";
    }
}
```

I know it is not possible to give more than one return statement but the response has the count of all 4 case counts.So If it does not find either one of the 4 case counts it should say eg.total closed cases:0" or total resolved cases:0 etc. So that's why give return statement. How do i give all 4 statements in one return statement or should do I need to use else if again to get my results.(I tried that and it throws error).Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Another thing to think about, I noticed that you declared a subroutine within your `if`/`else` statement.  In Perl, even if you declare a subroutine within an `if` statement or within another subroutine it will still be visible outside of the `if` statement or subroutine in which it was defined.  This can cause unpredictable results and is discouraged.  Lexically scoped subroutines are still experimental in Perl: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Lexical-Subroutines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may surprise you, but Perl will actually allow you to return multiple variables from one subroutine!

See link for details:
http://perlmeme.org/faqs/perl_thinking/returning.html

What I would do in this situation however, is create a hash for the output

```
sub foo {
    my %cases = ();

    $cases{closed} = 0;
    $cases{pending} = 0;
    $cases{resolved} = 0;
    $cases{assigned} = 0;

    return %cases;
}

# accessing cases outside of the subroutine
my %hash = foo();

print "CLOSED  : $hash{closed}\n";
print "PENDING : $hash{pending}\n";
print "RESOLVED: $hash{resolved}\n";
print "ASSIGNED: $hash{assigned}\n";
```

The output will look as follows:

```
CLOSED  : 0
PENDING : 0
RESOLVED: 0
ASSIGNED: 0
```

Hashes are great for storing multiple values by name and looking them up later, they are very useful when passing around a lot of data between functions.

Details about hashes:
http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~abatko/computers/programming/perl/howto/hash/

You can also pass hashes by reference if you have a large data structure that you don't want taking up a lot of memory, but I'd advise learning how to use a hash before learning how to pass them by reference.